# Windows Forms App (.Net Frameworks) Windows media player Sizing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-media-player

I've recently started working on windows forms, but I encountered an annoying bug and I don't know how to fix it. My windows media player gets bigger or starts having weird sizing while my application is running.
I have attached some images, can somebody please help?

[image: In editor]

[image: While running]

Comment: What help you want ?

Comment: @VimalCK I want it to stay the same size as in the editor.

Comment: That is design view. If you want to be in that size then set your form and media player width and height

Comment: @VimalCK Do I need to do that in properties?

Comment: @VimalCK I set the same size on max, it works now. Thank you!